# How to alert against multiple AWS SQS queues in Grafana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, alert, amazon-sqs

**Context:**
I'm using Grafana to monitor and alert against data in my AWS environment.

I need to be able to trigger an alert whenever the `ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage` metric in *any* of my SQS queues **starting with a given prefix** exceeds a certain threshold.

**Problem:** I need to trigger an alert on just a subset of my SQS queues, and not all of them.

**Attempted Solution:** I'm currently using the wildcard operator (`*`) value in the `Dimensions: Queue Name` field which blindly fetches the metric data from ***all*** my SQS queues, rather than just the ones that start with my given prefix.

Is there anyway to succinctly specify in bulk a subset of the SQS queues that Grafana should fetch the metric data from?

Comment: No, because CloudWatch API doesn't support it. Dirty workaround: Use * in Cloudwatch query and then "join" result with CSV datasource, where you define list of queue names, which need alerting.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind explaining this work around in more detail? Can this cloudwatch query be made in Grafana?

Comment: And where would the join take place?

Comment: Join must be done on the alert level. This is Grafana expert level.

Comment: What do you mean by expert level?